# Detecting outliers in circular data?

Tags: outliers, circular-statistics

I've a day of the year data about number of event occurence in different sites: 
[image]

A day of the year is circular data. I know that a usual detecting of outliers, for example by boxplot is no use here:

[image]
How can I detect outliers in this kind of situations?

Comment: Let's start from the output of the boxplot. Can you explain why you don't like it?

Comment: The number is average day in the year of event occurence. Because of that - for example - occurence of the event in 350 day of the year is earlier than 10 day of the year.

Comment: Shouldn't you be using a boxplot of the #occurrences?

Comment: No, number of the occurrences is not the case here.

Comment: Every event occurs only once a year (in most cases), although It can happened in January and December of the same year.

Comment: Isn't this just about the origin of your circular scale? Can't you just transform to a linear scale; say number of days - positive or negative - from a reference date e.g. median?

Comment: Do you mean - circular median?

Comment: No, that's not what I mean.

Comment: Missed edit window :-( Sorry, I should have said mode not median. If you can't add year information to give a linear scale then measure distance from somewhere in the "middle" of the data in your example about 40 days; so 10 days becomes -30, 365 days becomes -41. Exact location of "middle" doesn't really matter - mode seems a reasonable choice.

Answer (score 1):

I am battling similar problems at the moment and found some literature that help you.

Abuzaid, Mohamed, Hussin have designed and proposed circular boxplots, see:

Boxplot for circular variables (2012), doi 10.1007/s00180-011-0261-5 
http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=2347773

Outlier labeling via circular boxplot 
http://eprints.um.edu.my/10365/1/Outlier_labeling_via_circular_boxplot.pdf

There is also an R package that seems to include this:
OmicCircos: A Simple-to-Use R Package for the Circular Visualization of Multidimensional Omics Data http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3921174/

Answer (score 0):

One way to go about this would be to calculate the circular dispersion as in [this  answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/115123/55410). If you set the constant $c$ fairly high, ie. 2 or 3, you may view all observations outside the interval

$ \left[\hat\mu - c \hat\delta,  \hat\mu + c \hat\delta \right]$

as outliers. In that answer, you may also find some code to visualize this.