# Circular Data Analysis: Calculating Sample Circular Dispersion

Tags: standard-deviation, dataset, circular-statistics

Using Fisher (1993) *Statistical analysis of circular data* (p30-35), I calculated the sample circular dispersion of some timestamp data. However, I got circular dispersion greater than $1,000$. Is this possible? Does a circular dispersion of, for example, $361$ equivalent to a circular dispersion of $1$? Or did I do some massive calculation error?

Just as a reference, I also followed [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/114842/average-and-standard-deviation-of-timestamps-time-wraps-around-at-midnight). Thus, quoting Kees Mulder:

> 1. Denote the data by $\boldsymbol\theta = \{\theta_1, \dots, \theta_n\}.$ An estimate of the mean $\bar\theta$ can be calculated with
>
>    - $S=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sin(\theta_i)$,
>    - $C=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\cos(\theta_i)$,
>    - $\hat\mu = \text{atan2}(S, C)$. (See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2)
> 2. Calculate $\bar{R} = \frac{\sqrt{S^2 + C^2}}{n}$
> 3. Calculate the dispersion as suggested by whuber. I'm not sure why, but Wikipedia's definition seems to differ slightly from Fisher. I will use Fisher's:
>
>    - $\hat\delta = \frac{1 - \left[ (1/n) \sum_{i=1}^{n} \cos 2 (\theta_i - \hat\mu) \right]}{2\bar{R}^2}$
> 4. Then, choose some constant $c$  (1 is probably fine, but you may fine-tune). Then, the interval is given by
>
>    - $ \left[\hat\mu - c \hat\delta,  \hat\mu + c \hat\delta \right]$

Also, unfortunately, I cannot post my data.

Given the questions and comments below, I just want to clarify what I am looking for. I am primarily interested in whether the circular dispersion has an upper bound and how to interpret large circular dispersions. I am actually fairly confident that my calculations are correct, as long as the notes that I posted are correct.

Comment: What is your mean resultant length and sample size, in this case?

Comment: That is hard to say in words because I am calculating the sample circular dispersion for each individual in my dataset.

Comment: The average sample size (individual level) is 48. The average mean resultant length is 0.20

Comment: Could you add a fuller reference/citation than "Fisher (1995)", as you would in a paper or dissertation?

Comment: To make this self-contained, please define circular dispersion and give a small dataset with puzzling result sufficient to replicate (or correct) what you find.

Comment: If you want to know for sure whether you made a calculation error, I can't see an alternative to you posting your data! Or are you just interested in whether the circular dispersion has an upper bound?

Comment: I am primarily interested in whether the circular dispersion has an upper bound and how to interpret such large circular dispersions. I am actually fairly confident that my calculations are correct, as long as the notes that I posted are correct.

Comment: You are making a calculation error.  You don't have to reproduce your actual data: make a very small dataset with similar characteristics and see whether the problem recurs with it.  Then you can post that dataset.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is impossible to answer without toy data to replicate the issue.

Comment: I agree with whuber that there is likely a calculation error. A circular dispersion in the thousands is possible, with almost circular uniform data. However, it will almost certainly not occur at the same time as a mean resultant length of 0.20.

Comment: People were absolutely correct. I made a calculation error far in the beginning, which is why I was so convinced that I hadn't made an error (was doubling back over the theory, when it was far more basic)